# Induction is transitive; $\chi\uparrow^{G}_{K}= (\chi\uparrow^{H}_{K})\uparrow^{G}_{H}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $\chi$ is a *character* of $H$, the let the *character of* $G$ *induced* by $\chi$ to be $\chi\uparrow^{G}_{H}(g) = \frac{1}{|H|} \Sigma_{x \in G} \chi(x^{-1}gx)$ for all $g\in G$.

Prove that induction is transitive; that is if $K$ is normal subgroup of $H$, and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$, then we have

$\chi\uparrow^{G}_{K}= (\chi\uparrow^{H}_{K})\uparrow^{G}_{H}$.

Attempt: Let $\phi= \chi\uparrow^{H}_{K}$, then $ (\chi\uparrow^{H}_{K})\uparrow^{G}_{H}(h) = \phi\uparrow^{G}_{H}(h) = \frac{1}{|H|} \Sigma_{x \in G} \chi(x^{-1}gx)$.

Can someone please help me? I am stuck. Any help would really help

Comment: You don't need either subgroup to be normal here. It is just a matter of doing the computations, and remember that (by convention) the character is $0$ on anything not in the subgroup (i.e. when the conjugation sends you outside the subgroup).

Comment: Well, it is a bit simpler for normal subgroups, as the conjugation will never take you outside the subgroup. But it is still just a matter of writing up the definitions and manipulating the formulas a bit.

Comment: You just use the definition of the induced character (twice for one side) and check that they give the same.

Comment: What are maps? The definitions tells you the value at some element $g$, so you should check that the two characters have the same values on all $g$.

Comment: I am really not sure where the confusion is. The induced character is a map, and the definition tells you the value of this map at an element from the group.

Comment: unfortunately, I always get stuck on the same part.

Comment: Which part is that? In the question you have not even written up the definition of the composed induction.

Comment: I thought I was trying to do that. I guess I don't understand the notation. It's ok then

Comment: You only wrote up the formula for the induction from $H$ to $G$, not the combined induction from $K$ to $G$ through $H$.

Comment: So I know when $f(g(x))$ we evaluate first the $g(x)$ and then $f$ at that value. However, I dont know what I have to evaluate first in here.

Comment: You first evaluate the induction from $K$ to $H$, then the induction of this new character from $H$ to $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Part of proving formulas in mathematics is just unpackaging definitions.

What does $(\chi\uparrow_K^H)\uparrow_H^G$ mean? You say you know how to evaluate a composition of functions, putting one inside the other, but don't know what to evaluate first in this instance. This is simple: we learn very early on in mathematics that we evaluate expressions inside parentheses first. Indeed, since $K\subset H\subset G$, it's clear we must first induct a character of $H$ to a character of $K$ (i.e. apply $\uparrow_K^H$) and then induct from a character of $K$ to a character of $G$ (i.e. apply $\uparrow_H^G$). Therefore,

$$\left(\color{Green}{\chi\uparrow_K^H}\right)\uparrow_H^G(g)=\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{x\in G}\color{Green}{\chi\uparrow_K^H}(x^{-1}gx), $$

where we've simply replaced $\chi$ with $\color{Green}{\chi\uparrow_K^H}$ in the definition of $\chi\uparrow_H^G$. Now you can go further and replace the summands' induced characters $\chi\uparrow_K^H$ with the corresponding formula, just be sure to sum over (say) $y\in G$ so as not to repeat the letter $x$.